# Australia District/County level data needed

Tags: data-request, county, australia, district

I need to test a prototype and I need an all District dataset for Australia. It can be any data from Australia that is for every district.

Answer (score 5):

The link below is to the National Geospatial Agency (NGA) Geographic Name Server (GNS) for geographic features of Austrialia. The dataset has been converted to a linked CSV format and should be easy to parse. Your interest will be in records that are administrative divisions (NGA/GNS FCFC=A). The value of NGA/GNS DSG will tell you the type of administrative division:

ADM1: provinces and territories
ADM2: 2nd level divisions (e.g., shires)
ADMD: other smaller division (I think this includes districts)

http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/NGA/GNS/AS.zip

The link below is to the Australian Statistical Geography Standard fact sheets. These PDF documents explain how the Australian Census is broken down into geographic areas and contain links to various downloads. The smallest unit are mesh blocks, which consist of approx. 30 to 60 dwellings.

http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/D3310114.nsf/home/ASGS+Fact+Sheets

Answer (score 3):

[Someone has put together a giant SQLite database that holds pretty much all Australian Census data](http://ali.as/census/) at the smallest available geography from the [Australian Statistical Geography Standard (ASGS)](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/d3310114.nsf/home/australian+statistical+geography+standard+%28asgs%29)